# Given $E$ in $\mathbb R^n$, there exists an open $G$ containing $E$ such that $m^*(G)\le m^*(E) + \epsilon$. But $m^*(G-E) < \epsilon$ may not hold?

Tags: real-analysis, outer-measure

We let $m^*(E)$ denote the outer measure of a set $E$ in $\mathbb R^n$.

> Given $E$ in $\mathbb R^n$, there exists an open $G$ containing $E$
>   such that $m^*(G)\le m^*(E) + \epsilon$.

In general, since $G=E\cup (G-E)$ where $E\subset G$, we only have $m^*(G) \le m^*(E) + m^*(G-E)$, and we cannot conclude from $m^*(G)\le m^*(E) + \epsilon$ that $m^*(G-E) < \epsilon$.

Why $m^*(G-E) < \epsilon$ may not hold?

Comment: $E$ is  Lebesgue-measurable iff $m^*(A \cap E)+m^*(A$ \ $E)=m(A)$ for every Lebesgue-measurable $A.$...  There exists $E\subset [0,1]$  such that $m^*(E)=m^*([0,1]$ \ $E)=1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is possible then, for each $n$ we can find an open set $G_n$ such that $m^{*}(G_n\setminus E) <\frac 1 n$ . From this it follows that $m^{*}(\cap_n G_n\setminus E)=0$. Since $E \subset \cap_n G_n$ we can conclude that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable. But not every subset of $\mathbb  R$ is  Lebesgue measurable.

Comment: If there exists a Lebesgue measurable set $A \supset E$ such that $m^*(A \setminus E) = 0$, why does it follow that $E$ is Lebesgue measurable?

Comment: $E=A\setminus (A\setminus E)$. Since Lebesgue measure is complete $A\setminus E$ is Lebesgue measurable.